# Convert a user function to be a dataframe method (or equivalent)

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a simple function do variable expansion from a space delimited string to a list of variable names -- just ye old 'var1 var2 var3'.split() trick plus some simple wild card expansion.  (The actual function is at bottom of the question.)

```
df = pd.DataFrame( { 'cat': [1,2,3], 'car':     [7,8,9], 
                     'dog': [8,8,8], 'pelican': [2,4,6] } )

In [90]: cols( df, 'ca* pelican')
Out[90]: ['car', 'cat', 'pelican']
```

So far so good, and I can use it like this:

`df[ cols( df, 'ca* pelican') ]`

But the 'df' in the function call is redundant.  I'm wondering what I can do to instead do something like one of the following:

```
df[ cols('ca* pelican') ]
df.cols( 'ca* pelican' )
```

I know the latter is possible for a developer, but I don't think it is for a user, but also have done close to zero method writing so maybe there is a way?  Anyway, that is the question, whether I can implement one of the above two syntaxes.  And here is the actual function, if it matters (don't laugh, it's just a simple proof of concept!):

```
def cols( df, clist):
   clist = clist.split()
   cols = []
   for col in clist:
      if col.endswith('*'):
         for column in df.columns:
            if column.startswith(col[:-1]):
                cols.append(column)
      else:
         cols.append(col)
   return cols
```

Comment: why you are not using pandas [`.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas.DataFrame.filter) method, as in `df.filter(regex='ca*')` or `df.filter(regex='ca*|pelican')`?

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of how filter/regex can be used like that.  I would include something like that in a later version of the function.  However, this doesn't answer the core question and doesn't solve things like making the code more readable and allowing other variable expansions like VAR1-3 that would include VAR2 but not VAR4 for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can monkeypatch a function into DataFrame as a method.  For example, a function like

```
def both_sides(df, name):
    keep = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith(name)
            and c.endswith(name)]
    return df[keep]
```

can be added to the class as a method:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,4)), columns=["a", "ab", "aba", "b"])
>>> both_sides(df, "a")
          a       aba
0  0.775468  0.998379
1  0.430740  0.005156
2  0.231028  0.626962
3  0.194387  0.447785
>>> pd.DataFrame.both_sides = both_sides
>>> df.both_sides("a")
          a       aba
0  0.775468  0.998379
1  0.430740  0.005156
2  0.231028  0.626962
3  0.194387  0.447785
```

where the instance is passed in as the first argument (what we usually name `self`).  Whether mixing in added tools rather than simply using functions is a good idea is debatable, but there's nothing preventing you from doing it technically.

Comment: Thanks!  That's great and does answer my question but I'll leave it open a little while before checking.

Comment: As to whether mixing in added tools is a good idea or not is not "debatable" to me.  For my use case, a function like this very often saves typing and produces more readable code.  As a user I really appreciate all the developer work (and hope to eventually contribute myself) but I don't understand the developer attitude that we shouldn't customize our own environments for our own particular use cases.

Comment: here's a link to monkey patching in the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/faq.html; you can certainly patch if u want. the issue is it is not documented / standard, so a future reader will expect these methods as endemic to pandas even though they are local. so monkey patching in certain cases can produce more readable code; the only recommendation is to document / test

Comment: @Jeff  LOL, thanks for that very spot on link.  I was aware this sort of feature is something users often ask for and developers often say "use what is already there" so I figured I had to write a version for my own use.  FWIW, I think it happens frequently b/c it remains a pretty stark contrast between how convenient this sort of thing is in something like stata compared to pandas (pandas is also pretty young).  I'll try to join the github world soon when I have time.